# How to patch Linux Kernel?

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, linux-kernel

What is the command for patching Linux Kernel RHEL 8? I ran a security check on the RHEL 8 machine using OpenScap which gave me a list of CVE-links and a title with Kernel Security. After trying to upgrade the kernel and reboot the machine, the scan still gives me the same errors.

Comment: Are you sure this vulnerability actually exists in the new kernel (and you are running the new kernel?) Redhat often back port fixes/patches which are not always picked up by scanners.

Comment: The machine is currently running 4.18.0-80.11.2.el8_0.x86_64 and I'm following the guide provided by Red Hat: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/security_hardening/scanning-the-system-for-security-compliance-and-vulnerabilities_security-hardening for scanning.

Comment: The Linux kernel is only "patched" at the source code level.  The executable kernel file is not patched, but must be rebuilt from source code.

Comment: How is this done?

Comment: When running `yum updateinfo list security all` I get a long list of Important/kernel updates, example RHSA-2019:1167 Important/Sec. kernel-4.18.0-80.1.2.el8_0.x86_64.
And when I try to update one of them, example: `sudo yum update --advisory=RHSA-2019:1167` it tells me, Nothing to do. Complete!